"Flutter: Mismatch in Audio Playback and Highlighting When Pause/Resume Buttons Are Clicked Rapidly"
I'm developing a Flutter app that plays audio files sequentially from a list. When the "Pause" button is pressed, the playback stops, and the current audio file is marked as "played." On "Resume," the playback should continue from the next unplayed file.
Issue:
When the "Pause" and "Resume" buttons are clicked rapidly, the following problems occur:
The audio file being played is not always correctly highlighted.
The playback mismatches the highlighted file.
The "Continue" button sometimes becomes unresponsive.
Errors like Loading interrupted appear in the logs.
I've tried adding debounce logic and ensuring state consistency, but the issue persists.
The issue occurs when the "Pause" and "Resume" buttons are clicked in rapid succession. This results in mismatches where the selected file for parlaying and the fine name send for highlight is not similar, :and also the continue button stack when buttons are clicked in rapid succession.
 void pausePlayback() async {

    debounced(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () async {
        while (!callbacksCompleted) {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 50));
    }

    if (isPlaying && !isPaused) {
      await player.pause();
      setState(() {
        isPaused = true;
        isPlaying = false;
        showExtraButtons = true;
        isPausedButtonDisabled = true;
        isPlayButtonDisabled = false;
        iscontinueButtonDisabled = false;
      });

      if (currentPlayingVoice != null &&
          !highlightedIdentifiers
              .contains(currentPlayingVoice!.split('.').first)) {
        lastHighlightedIdentifier = currentPlayingVoice;
        widget.onSecondMethodCalled(currentPlayingVoice!.split('.').first);
      }
    }
    });  

  
  }

  Future<void> resumePlayback() async {
    await debounced(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () async {
      if (isPaused && !isLoading) {
        setState(() {
          isPaused = false;
          isPlaying = true;
          showExtraButtons = false;
          isPlayButtonDisabled = true;
          isPausedButtonDisabled = false;
        });

        await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
        _playAllVoices(resume: true);
      }
    });
  }

  void _playAllVoices({bool resume = false}) {
    if (isLoading) return;

    setState(() {
      showExtraButtons = false;
      isPausedButtonDisabled = false;
      isPlayButtonDisabled = true;
      isPlaying = true;
    });

    List<String> remainingVoices = List.from(bingoVoice)
      ..removeWhere((voice) => playedVoices.contains(voice));
    remainingVoices.shuffle();

    if (resume) {
      int lastPlayedIndex = remainingVoices.indexOf(currentPlayingVoice ?? '');
      if (lastPlayedIndex != -1) {
        remainingVoices = remainingVoices.sublist(lastPlayedIndex + 1);
      } else {
        // Handle the case where currentPlayingVoice is not found
        // (e.g., start from the beginning)
        print("Warning: currentPlayingVoice not found in remainingVoices");
      }
    }

    callbacksCompleted = false;
    bool isPlayingCurrent = false;

    Future<void> playNextVoice() async {
      if (isPaused || isPlayingCurrent || remainingVoices.isEmpty) return;

      isPlayingCurrent = true;

      currentFileName = remainingVoices.removeAt(0);
      playedVoices.add(currentFileName!);

      callbacksCompleted = true;

      String filePath = widget.selectedCheckBoxIndex == 0
          ? "bingoVoice/$currentFileName"
          : widget.selectedCheckBoxIndex == 1
              ? "bingoVoice2_single/$currentFileName"
              : "bingoVoice2_double/$currentFileName";

      try {
        if (isPlaying || isPaused) {
          await player.stop();
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
        }

        await player.setAsset(filePath);

        String identifier = currentFileName!.split('.').first;

        currentPlayingVoice = currentFileName; // Update currentPlayingVoice

        if (!highlightedIdentifiers.contains(identifier)) {
          highlightedIdentifiers.add(identifier);
          await player.play();
          widget.onSecondMethodCalled(identifier);
        }

        print("Playing voice: $filePath, Highlighting: $identifier");

        StreamSubscription<PlayerState>? subscription;
        subscription = player.playerStateStream.listen((state) {
          if (state.processingState == ProcessingState.completed) {
            subscription?.cancel();
            isPlayingCurrent = false;
            lastPlayedVoice = currentFileName;
            if (!isPaused && remainingVoices.isNotEmpty) {
              Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), playNextVoice);
            }
          }
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print("Error playing audio: $e");
        isPlayingCurrent = false;
        playNextVoice();
      }
    }

    playNextVoice();
  }



 void pausePlayback() async {

    debounced(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () async {
        while (!callbacksCompleted) {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 50));
    }

    if (isPlaying && !isPaused) {
      await player.pause();
      setState(() {
        isPaused = true;
        isPlaying = false;
        showExtraButtons = true;
        isPausedButtonDisabled = true;
        isPlayButtonDisabled = false;
        iscontinueButtonDisabled = false;
      });

      if (currentPlayingVoice != null &&
          !highlightedIdentifiers
              .contains(currentPlayingVoice!.split('.').first)) {
        lastHighlightedIdentifier = currentPlayingVoice;
        widget.onSecondMethodCalled(currentPlayingVoice!.split('.').first);
      }
    }
    });  

  
  }

  Future<void> resumePlayback() async {
    await debounced(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () async {
      if (isPaused && !isLoading) {
        setState(() {
          isPaused = false;
          isPlaying = true;
          showExtraButtons = false;
          isPlayButtonDisabled = true;
          isPausedButtonDisabled = false;
        });

        await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
        _playAllVoices(resume: true);
      }
    });
  }

  void _playAllVoices({bool resume = false}) {
    if (isLoading) return;

    setState(() {
      showExtraButtons = false;
      isPausedButtonDisabled = false;
      isPlayButtonDisabled = true;
      isPlaying = true;
    });

    List<String> remainingVoices = List.from(bingoVoice)
      ..removeWhere((voice) => playedVoices.contains(voice));
    remainingVoices.shuffle();

    if (resume) {
      int lastPlayedIndex = remainingVoices.indexOf(currentPlayingVoice ?? '');
      if (lastPlayedIndex != -1) {
        remainingVoices = remainingVoices.sublist(lastPlayedIndex + 1);
      } else {
        // Handle the case where currentPlayingVoice is not found
        // (e.g., start from the beginning)
        print("Warning: currentPlayingVoice not found in remainingVoices");
      }
    }

    callbacksCompleted = false;
    bool isPlayingCurrent = false;

    Future<void> playNextVoice() async {
      if (isPaused || isPlayingCurrent || remainingVoices.isEmpty) return;

      isPlayingCurrent = true;

      currentFileName = remainingVoices.removeAt(0);
      playedVoices.add(currentFileName!);

      callbacksCompleted = true;

      String filePath = widget.selectedCheckBoxIndex == 0
          ? "bingoVoice/$currentFileName"
          : widget.selectedCheckBoxIndex == 1
              ? "bingoVoice2_single/$currentFileName"
              : "bingoVoice2_double/$currentFileName";

      try {
        if (isPlaying || isPaused) {
          await player.stop();
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
        }

        await player.setAsset(filePath);

        String identifier = currentFileName!.split('.').first;

        currentPlayingVoice = currentFileName; // Update currentPlayingVoice

        if (!highlightedIdentifiers.contains(identifier)) {
          highlightedIdentifiers.add(identifier);
          await player.play();
          widget.onSecondMethodCalled(identifier);
        }

        print("Playing voice: $filePath, Highlighting: $identifier");

        StreamSubscription<PlayerState>? subscription;
        subscription = player.playerStateStream.listen((state) {
          if (state.processingState == ProcessingState.completed) {
            subscription?.cancel();
            isPlayingCurrent = false;
            lastPlayedVoice = currentFileName;
            if (!isPaused && remainingVoices.isNotEmpty) {
              Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), playNextVoice);
            }
          }
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print("Error playing audio: $e");
        isPlayingCurrent = false;
        playNextVoice();
      }
    }

    playNextVoice();
  }

